# ListPlot3D of two dimensional function

Tags: plotting

I have a two dimensional function that i need to draw a listPlot3D of this function at special nodes, as a simple example i wrote the following code:

```
 n = 20;
 Do[x[i] = Cos[i \[Pi]/n], {i, 0, n}];
 B = Table[{x[i], x[j], (x + y /. {x -> x[i], y -> x[j]})}, {i, 0, 
n}, {j, 0, n}];
ListPlot3D[B[[1]], InterpolationOrder -> 3, Mesh -> None]
```

but this shows nothing, I will appreciate if someone help me.

Comment: try `ListPointPlot3D[B[[1]]]` .

Comment: @Alucard, thank you,  I need a 3d plot from these nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 20;
Do[x[i] = Cos[i π/n], {i, 0, n}];
B = Table[{x[i], x[j], x[i] + x[j]}, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];

pts = Flatten[B, 1];

Show[
 ListPlot3D[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Mesh -> None],
 Graphics3D[{Blue, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your B is not a list of 3D-points, use `ListPlot3D[Flatten[B, 1]]`.
B[[1]] is a list but all points are on a line and don't span a 3D surface.

A slightly more Mathematica-looking code would use a function definition for x, which is probably what you had in mind to begin with.

```
n = 20;
x[i_] := Cos[i \[Pi]/n];
B = Table[{x[i], x[j], x[i] + x[j]}, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
ListPlot3D[Flatten[B, 1]]
```

Comment: thank you so much.